# Streaming android display using VLC

Tags: android, streaming, vlc

We currently have a Java Application that uses VLC to stream and view displays on Windows and Linux.  We now need to stream an Android display to the desktops. I have found several tutorials online on how to stream video and music from an Android device.  The problem is I need to stream the display at all times.  I have found other applications on the play store that allows for streaming from phone to desktop but not a library that I can use myself.   Can VLC for Android support streaming of the main display like its desktop counterpart?

Answer (score 0):

The most powerful tool for streaming your android screen on Windows is [Project Scrcpy on github](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)